# Gtk.main_quit() in Python script doesn't actually quit the Gtk main loop

Tags: python, gtk

I have a project that uses a Gtk.FileChooserDialog object to, obviously, allow a user to choose a file. Then, once the file is chosen, the dialog should disappear and the code should continue running.

While the dialog *does* disappear, the code does not continue on from after the `Gtk.main()` - my code seems to be stuck in the Gtk main loop.

Here's the code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class FileChooser(Gtk.FileChooserDialog):

        def __init__(self):

            dia = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", None,
                Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                 Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

            self.add_filters(dia)

            response = dia.run()
            if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
                print("Open clicked")
                print("File selected: " + dia.get_filename())
                path = dia.get_filename()
                dia.destroy()
                Gtk.main_quit() # <- Doesn't work?
            elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
                print("Cancel clicked")
                dia.destroy()
                Gtk.main_quit() # <- Doesn't work?

        def add_filters(self, dia):
            filter_any = Gtk.FileFilter()
            filter_any.set_name("Any files")
            filter_any.add_pattern("*")
            dia.add_filter(filter_any)

            filter_text = Gtk.FileFilter()
            filter_text.set_name('Text files')
            filter_text.add_mime_type('text/plain')
            dia.add_filter(filter_text)

            filter_py = Gtk.FileFilter()
            filter_py.set_name('Python files')
            filter_py.add_mime_type('text/x-python')
            dia.add_filter(filter_py)

            filter_img = Gtk.FileFilter()
            filter_img.set_name('Image')
            filter_img.add_mime_type('image/*')
            dia.add_filter(filter_img)

dialog = FileChooser()
dialog.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I've also attempted adding `dialog.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)` right after I create the `dia` object, but that doesn't work either.

Is there some glaring error that is making it so that calling `Gtk.main_quit()` doesn't make my code to exit the Gtk main loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only using the FileChooserDialog, you do not have to execute `Gtk.main()` or `Gtk.main_quit()`. Moreover, the inheritance from Gtk.FileChooserDialog is useless and can be removed.

This should work:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class FileChooser():

        def __init__(self):

            dia = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", None,
                Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                 Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

            self.add_filters(dia)

            response = dia.run()
            if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
                print("Open clicked")
                print("File selected: " + dia.get_filename())
                path = dia.get_filename()
            elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
                print("Cancel clicked")
            dia.destroy()

        def add_filters(self, dia):
            pass  # filters left out to make the snippet shorter

dialog = FileChooser()
```

Comment: A bit of additional explanation: `Gtk,Dialog.run()` executes its own nested GTK+ main loop. I think the problem with your code is that you're calling `Gtk.main_quit()` before `Gtk.main()`, and as such the quit flag seems to be ignored or overwritten. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Well, that works - the code continues running - but the dialog doesn't disappear! If I keep the `dialog.show_all()` line, the dialog closes, but I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "base.py", line 130, in <module>
    dialog.show_all()
AttributeError: 'FileChooser' object has no attribute 'show_all'`

Comment: Never mind! It's working now...not sure if I had messed up something or if Python was just derping, but it's working now! Thanks! +1 & accept!